# Set a reference group and change is value in cox regression with R

Tags: r, cox-regression

I want to perform a cox regression analysis, as shown in the picture, how can I do to set a reference group and change is HR into 1 and others are the specific value to the reference group?

[image]

Comment: have you even tried to google it and find something that could help you started (e.g. http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/5896_8f0fed2ccbbd42489276e554a05af87e.html). SO is not a coding service, it's there to help. You did not included your dataset!

Comment: I don't see where those examples include computation of user-chosen hazard ratios.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of worrying about which value of a covariate is a "reference" value, directly estimate the quantities of interest.  For example you can estimate and get confidence limits for all hazard ratios against x=7.  Here is the easy way when using the R `rms` package, which has a function `cph` which is a front-end for the R `survival` package `coxph` function.

```
require(rms)
dd <- datadist(mydata); options(datadist='dd')
# Example model with 3 predictors, interaction with the variable
# x1 that you are interested in.  So hazard ratios will depend on x2
# which we set to 10.  Omit x2 from list() if want to use the default
# value (median/mode of x2).  The following obtains hazard ratios for
# x1 = 6 7 8 9 against x1 = 7.
f <- cph(Surv(time, event) ~ x1 * x2 + x3, data=mydata)
contrast(f, list(x1=6 : 9, x2=10), list(x1=7, x2=10))
# Type ?contrast.rms to see how to plot these with confidence limits
```

To get survival probabilities use the `survest` function but note that the column heading you had is misleading because there is no *one* survival probability.